# mysql query error for timestamps

Tags: mysql

I hope the below error is self explanatory.I want to compare event_time with some few cart_time.I know that usually when we want any operation like this we need to use `in` but for timestamps how to compare it

```
 mysql> SELECT bsid
        FROM access_aug15
        WHERE event_time < (SELECT cart_time 
                            FROM chat_final 
                            WHERE bsid in (SELECT bsid  
                                           FROM access_aug15
                                           WHERE eventid="11"
                                           AND current_page not like  '%cart%'));

 ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

EDIT:Table structure access_aug15

```
  +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | vid               | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | bsid              | varchar(200) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | event_time        | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | eventid           | varchar(10)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | current_page      | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | departmentid      | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | form_id           | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | form_name         | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | page_title        | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | report_date       | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
  +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

table2:chat_final

```
  +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | bsid              | varchar(200) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | chat_time         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | cart_time         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | customerid        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | detail            | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | chat_type         | varchar(5)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query sub query(query inside another query) should return only one result.. But it returns more than one row. You need to modify your sub query. Please provide table structure and some data...Then i'll give you correct query

Comment: @Rajeev -  i think you need to add one more condition with "SELECT  "SELECT cart_time FROM chat_final "

Comment: @Rajeev please give some sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
select bsid from access_aug15 where event_time <(select cart_time from chat_final 
 where bsid in (select bsid from access_aug15 
 where eventid="11"  and current_page not like  '%cart%' 
 LIMIT 1) 
 LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: but i do not want to use a limit inside the subquery